# How to extract first font name of font-family value by using regex?

Tags: css, regex, vue.js

I want to extract the first font name without apostrophes of font family value by using Regex.

I don't know how to do it using Regex. Please guide me step by step to solve this problem. Thank in advance!

Input:
1. "'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif"

2. "Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif"

3. "Arial"

Expected output:
1. Helvetica Neue 
2. Arial
3. Arial

Comment: Are these strings coming from the stylesheet, the `<style>` element, the `style` attribute, or are they plain strings elsewhere (where)? What have you attempted, if anything?

Comment: Yes, need more context. Also, why do you think a regex is the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily `split()` the string by comma `,` grab the first part and `replace()` the single quotes to get your job done but if you need regex then this could be a solution.

```js
const regex = /"'?(.*?)'?(?:,|")/ig;
const str = `"'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif"
"Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif"
"Arial"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    if (groupIndex == 1)
      console.log(`${match}`);
  });
}
```